# Google Apps Script getPlainBody() from GmailMessage class regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, html-escape-characters

this is my first question on stackoverflow so plz let me know how I can improve readability for others.

Am trying to use regex on the string I obtained from getPlainBody() in GmailMessage Class but somehow it doesn't work when I try to do it directly on the string returned by getPlainBody() but works well when I manually add \n characters.

Code that works:

```
function RegularExp() {
  
  //manually entered \n characters into string that I copied and pasted from getPlainBody()

  var string = "Personal Message\nraw material: oak wood 100kg\nTRACKING NUMBER 7777777777\n<somehyperlink\nFROM SomeBrand"; 

  //my goal is to get: raw material: oak wood 100kg

  var regExp = new RegExp("(.*?)\n(?=TRACKING NUMBER)","g"); 

  var PersonalMessage = regExp.exec(string)[1];
  Logger.log(PersonalMessage); //works perfectly fine

}
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
for (var j in messages){
  var message = messages[j];
  var plainText = message.getPlainBody(); //getting plainbody of fedex mail of interest

  //trying to extract the personal message 
  var regExp = new RegExp("(.*?)\n(?=TRACKING NUMBER)","g");  
  var PersonalMessage = regExp.exec(plainText)[1];
  Logger.log(PersonalMessage); //won't show anything
}
```

My question is why does it work when I manually enter \n but not when I use the string that was returned from getPlainBody()? I'm using the exact same regex pattern and can't see why.

Below are the links I used to try to solve my problem (or I might just be dumb not being able to apply the solution to this issue)

[Newline in gmail app script getplainbody function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846922/newline-in-gmail-app-script-getplainbody-function)

[Google Apps Script: getPlainBody() weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68581689/google-apps-script-getplainbody-weird-behavior)

[Regex - google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869896/regex-google-apps-script)

Thanks

Comment: Try this: `(.*?)\\n(?=TRACKING NUMBER)`

Comment: @Alireza I tried that with and without the g flag but still didn't work :(

Comment: Try these: `([^\\n]+?)(?=\\nTRACKING NUMBER)` or `([^\n]+?)(?=\nTRACKING NUMBER)` hope it work for you.

Comment: @Alireza what... are you MAGICIAN?! ..?! works like charm.. i used my first regex code in regexr.com and other websites - worked fine but somehow it didn't work in google apps script. may i ask you how you solved this problem? regex is so useful but definitely a challenge.

Comment: I will write an answer and explanation for it.

Comment: Wiktor wrotes a good answer for it and I think it's enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `.` does not match a CR char in the JavaScript regex (ECMAScript flavor).

You can use

```js
var regExp = /(.*)(?=\r?\nTRACKING NUMBER)/g;
```

The regex matches

- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars (it does not match LF and CR chars)
- `(?=\r?\nTRACKING NUMBER)`  - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `\r?` - an optional CR (carriage return char)
  - `\n` - a line feed char
  - `TRACKING NUMBER` - some fixed string (at the end of the next line).